# testing record with join on 2 tables

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables, `FruitInventory` and `PeachInventory`, and they have the following columns:

```
FruitInventory 
FruitID | UserID | ....

PeachInventory
PeachID | FruitID | ...
```

I want to test if a user is authorized to access a certain PeachID based on whether or not he's authorized on the FruitID of the PeachID.

To test if he's authorized on the FruitID, I'm currently doing something like this:

```
public bool GetUserAuthorizedOnFruitID(int TheUserID, long TheFruitID)
{
   using (MyDataContext TheDC = new MyDataContext())
   {
      bool IsAuthorized = false;

      IsAuthorized = TheDC.FruitInventory
                          .Any(f => f.FruitID == TheFruitID && 
                                     f.UserID == TheUserID);

      return IsAuthorized;
   }
}
```

I know I could do a second query that would execute after this one and that would check if ThePeachID is part of TheFruitID but I was wondering how to do the authorization in one query, using a join that returns a boolean.

The function signature would be:

```
public bool GetUserAuthorizedOnPeachID(int TheUserID, long ThePeachID)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following schema based on what you have:

[image]

You can use this function/query:

```
public bool GetUserAuthorizedOnPeachId(int userid, int peachId)
{
    using(var context = new MyDataDataContext())
    {
        bool isAuthorized = false;
        isAuthorized = (from p in context.PeachInventories.Where(p => p.PeachId == peachId)
                                    join f in context.FruitInventories.Where(f => f.UserId == userid) on p.FruitId equals f.FruitId select p).Any();

        return isAuthorized;

    }
}
```

You can also use a chain in your LINQ as such:

```
public bool GetUserAuthorizedOnPeachIdUsingAChainQuery(int userid, int peachId)
{
    using (var context = new MyDataDataContext())
    {
        bool isAuthorized = false;

        isAuthorized = context.PeachInventories.Where(p => p.PeachId == peachId)
                        .Join(context.FruitInventories.Where(f => f.UserId == userid), p => p.FruitId, f => f.FruitId, (p, f) => f).Any();

        return isAuthorized;

    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm looking to test PeachID, so the function would be public bool GetUserAuthorizedOnFruitId(int userid, int peachId) instead of (int userid, int fruitId)

Comment: Updated to use PeachId versus FruitId, and switched the Queries around.

Comment: ok, cool, now I think it works; thanks. I had it downvoted because it wasn't the right query at all but I just upvoted because now it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this from memory:

```
IsAuthorized = (from f in TheDC.FruitInventory
                join p in TheDC.PeachInventory on p.FruitID equals f.FruitID
                where f.UserID == TheUserID
                   && p.PeachID == ThePeachID
                select p.PeachID).Any()
```

This will check if a user has access to a given peach by joining to the fruit inventory on the fruit Id.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution of an in chain linq query.

```
bool exists = TheDC.PeachInventory.Join(TheDC.PeachInventory, 
                             peach=> peach.FruitID,
                             fruit=> fruit.FruitID,
                             (peach, fruit) => fruit).Any(f => f.FruitID == TheFruitID &&                                                         
                                                          f.UserID == TheUserID)
```